# Keyboard shortcut to select item from Excel autocomplete list

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete

If I am entering some formula, the following dropdown appears:

[image]

How to finish it with one keystroke? How to remember it?

I've tried <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the same combinations with <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, the same combination with arrows....

Would like to have an answer here forever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you're placed on the item you want (either by scrolling down to it or typing enough so it's the only available suggestion), you can "take" the suggested autocomplete by double-clicking it with the mouse, or pressing the  <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.

Microsoft's [help page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Formula-AutoComplete-6d13daa5-e003-4431-abab-9edef51fae6b#bmenter_an_item_from_the_drop_down_list) provides some more useful information in this area, if you're interested.